# Ternary operator when casting a variable

Tags: php, types, casting, ternary-operator, shorthand-if

While writing `is_numeric($var) ? (Int)$var : (String)$var;`, I was wondering if it could be possible to move the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to the part where I *[cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)* the variable:

```
echo (is_numeric($var) ? Int : String)$var;
```

Not to my surprise, it didn't work:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$var' (T_VARIABLE)

Is this at all possible? Or maybe something close to what I'm trying to do? It's more of a curiosity thing than a need to use it.

Comment: Casting changes the way a value is interpreted by the left of the expression. A ternary returns a choice runtime values (not types). You need to cast the same variable differently, rather than choose types... Which I see @Rizier123 has added as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; this is not possible. The ternary operator expects an expression which the casting operator is not.

It would however be possible to use first-class functions, which are expressions, with the ternary operator like so:

```
$toInt = function($var) {
    return (int) $var;
};

$toString = function($var) {
    return (string) $var;
};

$foo = "10";

var_dump(call_user_func(is_numeric($foo) ? $toInt : $toString, $foo));
```

Comment: Accepted answer because of "_The ternary operator expects an expression which the casting operator is not_".

Answer (score 7):

Yes it's possible. This should work for you:

```
var_dump((is_numeric($var)?(int)$var :(string)$var));
```

As an example to test it you can easy do this:

```
$var = 5;
var_dump((true?(int)$var :(string)$var)); //Or var_dump((false?(int)$var :(string)$var));
```

Output:

```
int(5)  //string(1) "5"
```

**EDIT:**

They only way i could think of to do something similar to what you want would be this:

```
settype($var, (is_numeric($var)?"int":"string")); 
var_dump($var);
```

Comment: Good answer, but I was looking for a way to use it during the actual casting, like the code in my question. In the first part of my question I tried to imply I'm familiar with the _type juggling_ and _ternary operator_ concepts, but wondering whether this can be moved inside of the cast expression. Upvote anyway.

Comment: @ManeatingKoala Ah, now i see what you were trying to do, but this is not possible as far as i know

Comment: @ManeatingKoala updated my answer, this is what i could think of is pretty similar to what you want